# Is there a way to detect pattern of sound in incoming sound stream?

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm recording audio from microphone by using NAudio. By using timers i'm detecting the sound pattern (certain number of dB value reached in a given time) but i think its not the right way. Is there a way that i can get pattern of a sound in incoming audio like dial tone? Any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How exactly would you define a "pattern of a sound"?

Comment: While its hard for me to describe myself because of language barrier, read this. http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-4/Standing-Wave-Patterns

Comment: That is more text than I'm comfortable with reading to answer your question. At glance that page seems to be talking about harmonics and sine waves (which is what every sound is composed of), which does not really have much to do with dial tones. It is still unclear to me what exactly you are trying to detect

Comment: We need to record calls in our call center, and want to automate the process. Just have microphones connected to each PC from phone. It sends a dial tone which i'm trying to detect and then start recording if its detected.

Comment: That sounds unnecessarily complicated as there are solutions that would allow you to do that easier or even fully automatic (Skype-like applications, phones that can be connected to computer systems, ...). If you know the exact dial tone you could try to compare the recorded tone to the predefined one. This will however be error prone as any interference the microphone picks up (and microphone quality) will create noise in your audio signal. Further I am not sure how you plan on determining when to stop recording. I would recommend a different approach

Comment: I will check for silence to stop the recording, but again guessing work here. We will only keep phone calls > 10 minutes so can reduce the errors that way. So just looking for an easy way to detect patterns in sound. Thanks for the time and input. :)